# Regex.Replace with matched string in the replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to compactly insert a `<br />` tag before every line break in a string with regular expressions in C#. Can this be done? Currently, I am only able to *replace* the line break with the following:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />");
```

Can I modify this to include the matched text (i.e. either `\r\n`, `\r`, or `\n`) in the replacement?

Clearly, it can be done with a separate Match variable, but I'm curious if it can be done in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has a separate page just for [.NET's regex substitution magic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx).

While the others are correct that the most general approach is to capture something and write back the captured contents with `$n` (where `n` is the captured group number), in your case you can simply write back the entire match with `$&`:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />$&");
```

If you are doing this a lot then avoiding the capturing could be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Use parentheses to capture the line break, and use `$1` to use what you captured in the replace:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"(\r\n?|\n)", "<br />$1");
```

Comment: no need to capture anything. just use `$&` to write back the entire match. also the OP wanted to insert the tag *before* the line break ;)

Comment: @m.buettner: Yes, for this specific use you could get everything matched instead of capturing. Thanks for pointing out that the tag was requested to go first, I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) in your "replace" string:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"(\r\n?|\n)", "$1<br />");
```